# unknown attribute 'valoracion_id' for Rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

me sale ese error en el controlador

```
def create
val=Valoracion.all
    val.each do |app|
      Rating.create(:user_id => params[:rating][:user_id],
                    :app_id=> params[:rating][:app_id],
                    :valoracion_id => app.id,
                    :valoracion => params[:rating][:valoracion][app.id]
                    )                                                  
     end   
 end
```

rating.rb

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :app
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :valoracion
end
```

valoracion.rb

```
class Valoracion < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ratings
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu tabla `ratings`no tiene ninguna columna llamada `valoracion_id`. 
Debes de añadirlo en la base de datos.
Prueba con ejecutar en la terminal

`rails generate migration add_valoracion_to_ratings valoracion:references`

Esto generará un archivo de migración que añadirá la columna necesita. Para hacerlo efectivo, ejecuta:

`rake db:migrate db:test:prepare`